# Получить HEX число из VARCHAR в MySQL

Tags: hex, хеширование, mysql

Суть задачи:

Необходимо побитово (^) сравнить два HEX значения, одно приходит из php, второе лежит в базе в текстовом виде.

Проблема в том, что не удаётся вытащить второе значение в виде HEX числа, только как строку. Вот такой запрос выдаёт ответ "1":

```
SELECT 0xd9d8266fd990160f ^ 0xd9d8266fd990160e
```

Такой же запрос, в котором одно из значений достаётся из базы, выдаёт чёрт-те что, при этом в текстовом виде значения совпадают.

Первое число "вклеивается" в запрос на строне php примерно так:

`SELECT hash ^ 0x".$hash." FROM table_name`

И с этим проблем нет. Как заставить MySql считать текстовое значение столбца HEX числом?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так сработает:

```
SELECT 0xd9d8266fd990160f ^ CAST(CONV(SUBSTRING("0xd9d8266fd990160e",3,18),16,10) AS UNSIGNED);
```

З.Ы. Про то, чтобы хранить bigint, спрашивать, видимо, не стоит?

Comment: Изначально данные нужны были именно в строковом формате, а заморачиваться с конвертацией не хотелось. Потом задача несколько изменилась, а переделывать базу было лень). Подобный вариант решения уже подсказали на другом ресурсе, но мы упёрлись в ограничение MySQL - он падает, если сумма операндов больше 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.
____

Прошу прощения, ваш вариант работает полностью. Я так понял, каст в unsigned высвободил больше места для самого значения, правильно?

Comment: @nilagor, каст в unsigned переводит в unsigned bigint. Если оба операнда помещаются (не сумма) в диапазон, xor тоже должен сработать. Не знаю, откуда взялась мысль про сумму, может быть, вы кастовали в signed, ну, там в два раза меньше макс значение, из-за этого могло сломаться...